# If I make an app at API level 21 (5.0), will it work with newer version of android?

Tags: android, sdk, android-version, android-api-levels

I just started to use android 2 weeks ago.

I have successfully made my first app with API level 21 (5.1 Lollipop).
My phone's android is also 5.1 Lollipop.

I wonder if my app will work with all newer version of android,
such as 6.0 marshmallow or 7.0 nougat? Or do I need to provide
updates?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will work on newer versions as long as you do not have `maxSdkVersion` set to 21

In your application manifest, you will find up to three attributes:

`android:minSdkVersion`

`android:targetSdkVersion`

`android:maxSdkVersion`

If your max is set to 21 then it will not work with newer versions. You might not even have a max set.

You likely have your target set at 21 or your min set at 21, or both...

You can learn more about [`<uses-sdk>` here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

One thing to note : 4.4 kitkat still has 17% of the API distribution so you might want to set your minSdkVersion to 19. You can find a weekly updated distribution [chart here](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Platform)

Comment: Thanks. So Android is very different from windows after all.

Comment: BTW, in the file [ AndroidManifest.xm; ], I saw only <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />.